# Project>Clean in eclipse deleted all my classes, is there a way to revert/undo?

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I'm using eclipse to create an Android app for my final year project.
Following some advice on a website, I used the Project->Clean function to maybe try and solve an error I was getting. The clean completely wiped my current classes leaving only the R.java and BuildConfig.java classes.

Is there a way to undo the changes or revert them? 
My last backup is several hours of complex work which I'd have trouble re-creating.

Comment: Try to close and open your eclipse. Check in your local directory whether the files are still available

Comment: I think there is no way to revert it in eclipse, except you have all these files in a version control system (e.g. SVN or Git). Which OS are you working on? In case of Windows you might check for ShadowCopies on Windows Explorer. Other tools like GetDataBack (http://www.runtime.org) could help you to recover your files.

Comment: Right click on the project and select `Restore from Local History`. Project > Clean should only delete .class files and the like, it should not touch source